# The article class ignores 14pt

Tags: fontsize

I need font size = 14 in article document, but when I change

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
```

to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}
```

font becomes even smaller.
How to change font size?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Document class `article` only supports `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`. The default is `10pt`.
Option `14pt` is unknown, therefore you are getting `10pt`.

You can get larger sizes with `extsizes`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
```

It supports `8pt`, `9pt`, `10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt`, `14pt`, `17pt` and `20pt`.

Package `geometry` (or `hyperref` or some graphics drivers like `pdftex.def` or …) set the paper size to the output media.

Comment: Just a note for [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) [Org mode](http://orgmode.org/) users, you'd have to add-to-list [org-latex-classes](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/66443) definition for extarticle similar to existing one for article to use it with [LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS](http://orgmode.org/manual/Header-and-sectioning.html)

Comment: Perhaps a little extra information about which sizes `extarticle` supports would make this a more informative answer.

Comment: It works. But caution, it does not support 15pt, 16pt!