# \today and language (babel, xepersian)

Tags: fonts, babel, languages, xepersian

I'm using xepersian for my article but in one page I need to add Gregorian calendar date. so I add:

```
\usepackage[british]{babel}
```

and then where I want the date:

```
\selectlanguage{british}
{\large \today}
```

butthen where ever I use today it writes Gregorian instead of persian (still in persian but uses Gregorian calender) and figure caption texts (like Fig.) is in english instead of persian.

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{article}

%\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

Like this the printed date is from persian calendar like this (reads 16th of khordad 1393):

[image]

but when I uncomment that line it will be english language in persian like this(reads 6th of june 2014):

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to test?

Comment: Is there a babel option for persian? than you could try `\usepackage[persian,english]{babel} ... \begin{document}
\selectlanguage{persian}`

Comment: I don't think so. I looked on the internet but couldn't find anything. I also tried adding persian in that line but it didn't recognize it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things up front:

1. As `XePersian` is relying on the `XeTeX` engine, I would recommend using [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) instead of `babel`.
2. The `article` document class cannot use the `14pt` option; for more information, take a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70384/8432).

---

The Problem in your case is that `XePersian` clearly changes all [western numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) (123) into [genuine Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) (١٢٣), even though the `XB Niloofar` font contains both. Therefore, you need to tell `XeTeX` to use a different font than `XePersian` uses with `\settextfont`. If you do not specify a different font, `XePersian` will be used for typesetting, which will of course substitute the numerals.

First, of course, you need to tell `XeTeX` there is another language besides Farsi. You should use `polyglossia` to set this up: `\setotherlanguage[]{english}`. Then you must tell `polyglossia` to use a different font for all English text with `\newfontfamily\englishfont{XB Niloofar}`. This can of course be the exact same typeface as your `XePersian` `\settextfont`, but this time, it will not go through `XePersian` and thusly use the correct number forms. In the document, use `\textenglish{}` or `\begin{english}` to switch to an English environment.

Using the above suggestions will yield the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

%\setdefaultlanguage[]{farsi}
\setotherlanguage[]{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{XB Niloofar}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont{XB Niloofar}


\begin{document}
\today

\textenglish{\today}
\end{document}
```

which gives this output:

[image: XePersian output]

---

On a side note, setting `\setdefaultlanguage[]{farsi}`, which would be normal practice with `polyglossia`, does not work, because it clashes with `XePersian`, therefore it is commented out here but you are welcome to delete it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and the code. It did just what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

All you had to do was looking at `xepersian` documentation. No extra package required, no `babel` no `polyglossia`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\today

\latintoday
\end{document}
```