# Document font sizes different as 10, 11 or 12 pt

Tags: fonts, size

I want the font size of a whole document to be 14pt or 16pt. Or I noticed, that for 10pt, 11pt or 12pt, everything is fine. For all other font sizes, the document is written in 10pt font size. Is there a way to change that? I am using TexStudio (does it change something? I doubt it).

For example, the code here (with 16pt asked) gets a 10pt font size:

```
\documentclass[16pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\author{R. Pereboom}
\begin{document}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

I get the same result with any font size except 10, 11 or 12pt. For instance, 8pt is not working either.
I hope I am explicit enough...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The article class ignores 14pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70381/the-article-class-ignores-14pt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard classes only support 10pt, 11pt and 12pt.

You can use the `fontsize` package that does a good work in guessing the relative sizes. For Computer Modern you need also `fix-cm`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[fontsize=16pt]{fontsize}

\begin{document}

Some text

{\small Some small text\par}

{\footnotesize Some footnote size text\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If `17pt` is a close-enough substitute for `16pt` for you, I suggest you replace

```
\documentclass[16pt,a4paper]{article} % '16pt' not a valid option
```

with

```
\documentclass[17pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
```

The `extarticle`, `extreport`, and `extbook` classes are just like `article`, `report`, and `book`, except that they recognize `8pt`, `9pt`, `14pt`, `17pt`, and `20pt` as additional font size options. Of course, the basic `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt` options continue to work too.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class (which can be used to typeset documents in the style of `book`, `report` and `article` classes)  provides type size options 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt, 25pt, 30pt, 36pt, 48pt and 60pt, plus an author-defined type size. Within a document, depending on the type size option, you can use fonts ranging from 4pt to 132pt. See the manual `texdoc memoir` section 3.2 for more information.

These are close to, but do not exactly match, those provided by traditional lead type. From [www.arionpress.com/mandh-pricelist-ordering](http://www.arionpress.com/mandh-pricelist-ordering) they can provide lead type in the following pt sizes:

6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 60, 72, 84

In LaTeX be carefull about using fonts other than Knuth's. Ideally the shape of each font size should be different. A font designed at 25pt will differ, perhaps significantly, from a 10pt scaled up to 25pt. Font scaling is not linear --- different parts of a character may need to be treated differently. Perhaps horizontal lines made thicker and verticals made thinner, or maybe the other way around.