# About LaTeX document preamble

Tags: math-mode, document-classes, preamble, sourcecode, documentclass

This migh be a silly question but I ask to you LaTeX veterans for help in improving my LaTeX-document preamble. The following is what I usually run as predefinite preamble, but I suspect that I could improve this a lot.

Sure you may say "it's personal, you decide what you need", and I do agree. But what I am asking for, is an improvement about the page style (the current one is good, but is really good?), and then I would like to know why the 12 pt. part at the beginning cannot be changed. If I set, to say, 18 pt, the text actually becomes smaller!

Also: is "danish" a good style?

Any suggestions? Thank you so much!

P.s. I need a mostly scientific preamble, that is: rich of maths modes, with a good looking page style. Not necessarily for articles and papers only, as well as for notes, exams and so on.

```
\documentclass[danish, a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=0.8in, right=0.8in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[paperheight=29cm, paperwidth=20cm, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}

%\usepackage{newpxtext} 
%\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}


\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{"Immagini/"}}
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pspicture}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{midpage}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

Comment: The 12pt is because of [fontsize - The article class ignores 14pt - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70381/the-article-class-ignores-14pt)

Comment: (1) There are not 18pt in standard classes, so the default is applied (10pt), but you can use 17pt or 20pt in `extarticle` class, for instance. (2)    "danish" is not a style, is an option of babel package placed here (load first = second language). As single idiom, this  adapt your document to the danish language (e.g., change the automatic title  "Index"  to "Inhold",etc.) but as second languaage you hardly will notice nothing,  except if you have some text marked as danish (3) Without doubt, the best preamble is an empty preamble where you add only the strictly needed.

Comment: I get the impression you are including every package you have ever used in any document.  I prefer to never include a package unless it is needed.